# Junit & intelliJ: Running all tests in a folder && without a certain @Tag

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea, junit5

It seems like intellJ will let me run either:

- all tests in a certain folder
- OR, all tests with/without a certain tag

If I want to run all tests in a folder, I do it like this:

[image]

If I want to run all tests without a certain @Tag, I do it like this:

[image]

But I want to do both!  I want to run all tests inside that folder PLUS I want to run all tests that don't have a certain @Tag.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it's not possible for now.
Here is the feature request to vote for: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-245281